# dealing with noise in hdbscan

Tags: noise, hdbscan

I have been testing hdbscan from the scikit learn package with a small instance of (x,y) points "point_coord" and the resulting clusters do not really make sense to me. Given the small size of the sample, I am allowing a single cluster.

I would expect two clusters: 4th and 5th point clustered together versus the rest the points.

```
point_coord=[[0,0],[1,1],[0,1],[50,40],[50,45],[2,3],[1,2]]

test=pairwise_distances(point_coord)

clusterer= hdbscan.HDBSCAN( allow_single_cluster=True,                
metric='precomputed')

clusterer.fit(test)
```

However, the resulting clusterer.labels are:

[-1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]

Answer (score 4):

There are few things you have to consider:

1 - HDBSCAN is a noise aware clustering algorithm. So the -1 results in the output are data considered as outliers and excluded from clustering.
From 
[Documentation](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#q-hdbscan-is-failing-to-separate-the-clusters-i-think-it-should)

> Importantly HDBSCAN is noise aware – it has a notion of data samples
>   that are not assigned to any cluster. This is handled by assigning
>   these samples the label -1

2 - The dataset is very small and the `min_samples` and `min_cluster_size` parameters are not set. So HDBSCAN is using the default parameters which set a minimum cluster size to 5. You can check the used parameters in the output of the  `clusterer.fit(distance_matrix)` command.

```
HDBSCAN(algorithm='best', allow_single_cluster=False, alpha=1.0,
        approx_min_span_tree=True, cluster_selection_method='eom',
        core_dist_n_jobs=4, gen_min_span_tree=False, leaf_size=40,
        match_reference_implementation=False, memory=Memory(location=None),
        metric='precomputed', min_cluster_size=5, min_samples=None, p=None,
        prediction_data=False)
```

Please refer to documentation([Parameter Selection for HDBSCAN](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter_selection.html?highlight=noise)) for understanding how to properly configure the algorithm.

Here it is a corrected version of your code with the plot of the cluster dendrogram.

```
point_coord=[[0,0],[1,1],[0,1],[50,40],[50,45],[2,3],[1,2]]
distance_matrix=pairwise_distances(point_coord)
clusterer= hdbscan.HDBSCAN(metric='precomputed', min_samples=1,min_cluster_size=2)
clusterer.fit(distance_matrix)
print(clusterer.labels_)
clusterer.single_linkage_tree_.plot()
```

Output:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array(point_coord)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
```

output: `array([1,1,1,0,0,1,1])`

I agree that it should be something like:
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)